# Difference between bit and sbit?

Tags: embedded, 8051

What is the difference between the `bit` and `sbit` keywords in Keil C51 for the 8051 Microcontroller?

When should `sbit` be used and when `bit`?

Some examples would be very helpful.

Comment: The question is not clear.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It's rather clear. It's KEIL compiler extensions for 8051 processors, and well documented at http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_le_bit.htm and http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_le_sbit.htm

Comment: @nos One more it is obvious that the question is not clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should help you :

> **BIT**
>
> C51 provides you with a bit data type which may be used for variable
>   declarations, argument lists, and function return values. A bit
>   variable is declared just as other C data types are declared. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> static bit done_flag = 0; /* bit variable */
>
> bit testfunc (    /* bit function */
>   bit flag1,  /* bit arguments */
>   bit flag2)
> {
> .
> .
> .
> return (0);   /* bit return value */
> }
> ```
>
> All bit variables are stored in a bit segment located in the internal
>   memory area of the 8051. Because this area is only 16 bytes long, a
>   maximum of 128 bit variables may be declared within any one scope.
>
> Memory types may be included in the declaration of a bit variable.
>   However, because bit variables are stored in the internal data area of
>   the 8051, the data and idata memory types only may be included in the
>   declaration. Any other memory types are invalid.
>
> The following restrictions apply to bit variables and bit
>   declarations:
>
> - Functions which use disabled interrupts (#pragma disable) and functions that are declared using an explicit register bank (using n)
>     cannot return a bit value. The C51 compiler generates an error message
>     for functions of this type that attempt to return a bit type.
> - A bit cannot be declared as a pointer. For example:
>
>   bit *ptr
> - An array of type bit is invalid. For example:
>
>   bit ware [5]
>
> **SBIT**
>
> With typical 8051 applications, it is often necessary to access
>   individual bits within an SFR. The C51 compiler makes this possible
>   with the sbit data type. The sbit data type allows you to access
>   bit-addressable SFRs. For example:
>
> ```
> sbit EA = 0xAF;
> ```
>
> This declaration defines EA  to be the SFR bit at address 0xAF. On the
>   8051, this is the enable all bit in the interrupt enable register.
>
> **NOTE:**
>
> Not all SFRs are bit-addressable. Only those SFRs whose address is
>   evenly divisible by 8 are bit-addressable. These SFR’s lower nibble
>   will be either 0 or 8; for example, SFRs at 0xA8 and 0xD0 are
>   bit-addressable, whereas SFRs at 0xC7 and 0xEB are not. SFR bit
>   addresses are easy to calculate. Add the bit position to the SFR byte
>   address to get the SFR bit address. So, to access bit 6 in the SFR at
>   0xC8, the SFR bit address would be 0xCE (0xC8 + 6).
>
> Any symbolic name can be used in an sbit declaration. The expression
>   to the right of the equal sign (=) specifies an absolute bit address
>   for the symbolic name. There are three variants for specifying the
>   address.
>
> Variant 1:
>
> ```
>  sfr_name ^ int_constant
> ```
>
> This variant uses a previously-declared sfr (sfr_name) as the base
>   address for the sbit. The address of the existing SFR must be evenly
>   divisible by 8. The expression following the carat symbol (^)
>   specifies the position of the bit to access with this declaration. The
>   bit position must be a number in the range 0 to 7. For example:
>
> ```
> sfr PSW = 0xD0;
> sfr IE = 0xA8;
>
> sbit OV = PSW ^ 2;
> sbit CY = PSW ^ 7;
>
> sbit EA = IE ^ 7;
> ```
>
> Variant 2:
>
> ```
> int_constant ^ int_constant
> ```
>
> This variant uses an integer constant as the base address for the
>   sbit.  The base address value must be evenly divisible by 8. The
>   expression following the carat symbol (^) specifies the position of
>   the bit to access with this declaration. The bit position must be a
>   number in the range 0 to 7. For example:
>
> ```
> sbit OV = 0xD0 ^ 2;
> sbit CY = 0xD0 ^ 7;
>
> sbit EA = 0xA8 ^ 7;
> ```
>
> Variant 3:
>
> ```
> int_constant
> ```
>
> This variant uses an absolute bit address for the sbit. For example:
>
> ```
> sbit OV = 0xD2;
> sbit CY = 0xD7;
>
> sbit EA = 0xAF;
> ```
>
> **NOTES :**
>
> Special function bits represent an independent declaration class that
>   may not be interchanged with other bit declarations or bit fields.
>
> The sbit data type declaration may be used to access individual bits
>   of variables declared with the bdata memory type specifier

Source : 
[BIT](http://www.fsinc.com/reference/html/com97cl.htm) and [SBIT](http://www.fsinc.com/reference/html/com9agk.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Check this [forum](http://www.mikroe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=23216):

> The main difference between the bit and sbit is that you can declare
>   sbit a varible in a unit in such way that it points to a specific bit
>   in the SFR register. In the main program you need to specify to which
>   register this sbit points to.
>
> ```
> dim Abit as sbit sfr external ' Abit is precisely defined in some external file, for example 
>
> in the main program unit
> ...
> implements
> ....
> end.
> ```
>
> The mikroBasic PRO for PIC compiler provides a bit data type that may
>   be used for variable declarations. It can not be used for argument
>   lists, and function-return values, there are no pointers to bit
>   variables, and an array of type bit is not valid.
>
> ```
> dim bf as bit  ' bit variable
> ```
>
> sbit is not a new variable and does not take extra memory space, while
>   with a bit different, will the new variable, which further defines and
>   takes additional space in memory.

Also check the references(*added by nos in comments*):

- [Bit](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_le_bit.htm)
- [SBit](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_le_sbit.htm)

Answer (score 1):

sBIT is a special type of register used in 8051 microcontroller and are used for accessing individual bits that are declared with bdata while Bit is used to define a single-bit variable.